# Putting things outside Bootstrap's grid without scroll

Tags: html, css, grid, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap and the non-fluid non-responsive grid at 940px. I want to insert an image rotator outside it at 1200px, which I succeeded, but when I make the the browser window smaller I get a horizontal scrollbar at 1200px. I want the browser to center at the 940px grid, so when I make the window smaller the horizontal scrollbar will not appear before I'm at 940px.

I know that I can use a background-image width 100% width and centered, but what if I want to put in normal content and divs etc width fixed width?

Here's a sketch I made: http://f.cl.ly/items/1x3f3w1B1X461q3b2H21/bootstrap-grid.jpg

So for example I have a div at far right with the image counter. If you have a large screen above 1200px, then fine, you can see it, but if you only have 1024px then you won't see it, and you'll now have any horizontal scrollbars either.

Comment: Use media queries different style for different width, I think that will solve your problem

Comment: But I'm not sure how to make the image rotator narrower with media queries. In that case the images must also be resized in height, and I don't want that. Isn't it possible to set something outside the main page wrapper without horizontal scroll?

Comment: You can do its for wide screens & display another slider on small screens & hiding wide slider.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to overflow-x: none; and then trigger the scrollbar with javascript when the window width is below 940. I don't believe there is any other way.